# I'm getting an error while trying to make a phone book with a binary tree in Scheme

Tags: scheme, containers, binary-tree

1. Write a function (make-phone-book name number left right) that takes a name, a phone number and left and right subtrees and creates a new phone book tree. Your tree nodes should be of the form ((name . phone-number) left-tree right-tree), where name and phone-number are a pair.

   I got:

   ```
   (define (make-phone-book name number left right)
   (list (cons name number) left right))
   ```
2. Write functions get-name, get-number, get-left and get-right which return the appropriate data from a given phone book.

   I got:

   ```
   (define (get-name book)(caar book))
   (define (get-number book)(cdar book))
   (define (get-left book)(cadr book))
   (define (get-right book)(cddr book))
   ```
3. Write a function (insert book name number) which inserts a new entry into the phone book. You can use the builtin functions ‘string=? ’ , ‘string>? ’ and ‘string

   ```
   (define (insert book name number)
   (cond
   ((null? name) make-phone-book name number '() '())
   ((string=? (get-name book) name) book)
   ((string<? (get-name book) name) (make-phone-book name number
                                        (insert (get-left book) name number)
                                        (get-right book)))
   ((string>? (get-name book) name) (make-phone-book name number
                                        (get-left book)
                                        (insert (get-right book) name
   number)))))
   ```

It gives the error:

```
caar: contract violation
  expected: (cons/c pair? any/c)
  given: '("Harry" 5550011)
```

Comment: You violated the contract.  It expected a `(cons/c pair? any/c)`, and you provided it with `'("Harry" 5550011)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several small errors.

1. `(null? name)` should be `(null? book)`.
2. In that same case, you forgot to bracket the result expression: `(make-phone-book name number '() '())`
3. When you recurse, you should pass `(get-name book)` and `(get-number book)` to `make-phone-book`, not `name` and `number`.

When testing, only use `make-phone-book` and `insert` to create the trees.
Don't write trees by hand.

Comment: (insert '(("Stanley" 5550004) ("Larry" 5550007)) "Esmerelda" 5550021)
'(("Esmerelda" . 5550021) ("Larry" 5550007) ())

Comment: But when I try (insert '(("Stanley" 5550004) ("Larry" 5550007)) "Esmerelda" 5550021) It returns
'(("Esmerelda" . 5550021) ("Larry" 5550007) ())

Comment: @WentaoHu `'(("Stanley" 5550004) ("Larry" 5550007))` is not a valid phone book. Use `make-phone-book` and `insert` to build the tree all the way.

Comment: @WentaoHu I'd missed a couple of other bugs. See edit.

Comment: In addition, `get-right` has wrong definition since the node is made with `list` and not `list*`